# Spring Integration NotSerializableException on jdbc inbound-channel-adapter update query

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have a jdbc inbound-channel-adapter which is defined as shown below. I'm using a MySQL dataSource. I want to update the status of rows that have been polled. I'm trying to follow this document: [spring integration ref. mannual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html) . My understanding is that the :id should map to the set of all id's returned by the SELECT query.

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="targetChannel" data-source="dataSource"
    query="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE status=''" row-mapper="myRowMapper"
    max-rows-per-poll="500"
    update="UPDATE mytable SET status='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE id in (:id)">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The SELECT query executes fine and I have ensured that all the resulting rows are mapped by the RowMapper as expected, however while it tries to update using the given UPDATE query, I get the following exception:

```
2016-09-23 14:57:29.361 ERROR 15580 --- [task-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE mytable SET status='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE id in (?)]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:108)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:894)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:287)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.executeUpdateQuery(JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.java:181)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.poll(JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.java:173)
at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.receive(JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:209)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:3829)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:3559)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement.setObject(JDBC42PreparedStatement.java:68)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:440)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:150)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:244)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:3818)
... 33 more
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably don't have your class for mytable as a subclass of Serializable interface. You data objects have to implement that interface in order to be persisted to the database.

Comment: Correct `:id` should be simply evaluated against the object from the `SqlParameterSource`. You have to be sure that your `myRowMapper` returns the proper POJO with `getId()` which is really of the proper type to be mapped to the subsequent UPDATE. Since we don't have that info, we can't help you.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Yes, the problem was in my POJO, like I have mentioned in my answer. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, thanks to Artem Bilan. I assumed that :id would map to "id" among the column names in the SELECT's result set and not to getId() on the POJOs. My RowMapper was mapping the "id" into "requestId" in the POJO. That was the mistake.